# Generic hosting with custom DI tries to get wrong type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm using the [generic hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in .NET Core, and I've created an `IHostedService` that is instantiated in my generic host like this:

```
IHostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) => {
        services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
     });
```

Where `MyService` is just a simple skeleton:

```
public class MyService : IHostedService {
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { }
    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { }
}
```

This works just fine.

However, if I try to use a custom DI instead of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` the `AddHostedService()` request an `IHost` instead of an `IHostedService`. I can see that this is happening by debugging the custom `IServiceProvider`:

```
public class MyCustomProvider : IServiceProvider {

    SomeContainer _someContainer;

    public MyCustomProvider(SomeContainer someContainer) {
        _container = container;
    }
    public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
        return _container.Get(serviceType);
        // This is only called once, and serviceType is typeof(IHost)
    }
}
```

Where the generic host is now set up like this:

```
IHostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder()
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new MyContainerFactory())
    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) => {
        services.AddHostedService<MyService>();
     });
```

With `MyContainerFactory` set up like this:

```
class MyContainerFactory : IServiceProviderFactory<SomeContainer> {
    public SomeContainer CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services) {
        return SomeContainer.SetupStuff().Create();
    }
    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(SomeContainer container) {
        return new MyCustomProvider(container);
    }
}
```

Seeing as my custom DI container is being called successfully I suspect that there's nothing wrong with how my container is set up. It obviously can't find any `IHost` because `MyService` inherits from `IHostedService`, but why does it try to get an `IHost` in the first place? Something must be wrong, but I just can't understand where!

Why is my generic host trying to create an `IHost`, instead of `IHostedService`, when calling `AddHostedService()`

Comment: What "custom DI" are you using here? Are you really building a container yourself or are you using one of the existing ones? This is important, because most DI containers already have integration available for .NET Core, but a good share of them don't integrate using `UseServiceProviderFactory` and other constructs. This pattern is called [Conforming Container](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/) and you can find a detailed discussion on why some containers do not support this [here](https://blog.simpleinjector.org/2016/06/whats-wrong-with-the-asp-net-core-di-abstraction/).

Comment: I'm using `System.Composition`

Comment: Ahh.. you are using MEF. I'm unsure whether the composition model of MEF is compatible with the registration API implicitly defined by `IServiceCollection` and it might not be easy an easy task to define a fully compatible MEF adapter. You might, instead, try the approach taken by Castle Windsor, Ninject, and Simple Injector, which is to use MEF as your *application container* and keep the built-in container in place to create framework components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the HostBuilder add all the Generic Host specific services to the built-in `IServiceCollection` which is passed to the `IServiceProviderFactory`, however in your factory those services are ignored.

This causes the newly generated `SomeContainer` to miss the required basic services (e.g. `IHost`, `IConfiguration`, `ILoggerFactory`, etc) to run.

The `IHost` that is "missing" (or rather not available in your custom DI), is the [class](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/1da228d28fdfcfb2d77241c4e0413efec1beeafd/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/Internal/Host.cs#L47) the runs all the hosted services.

The solution is to add all the services (or at least `IHost`, but might cause some other missing services later on) to your `SomeContainer` in `IServiceProviderFactory.CreateBuilder`.